# Can i add any mi device virtual device in genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I am getting the lots of crash reports from the xiaomi mi phone regarding the permission thing in my android app. Can it be possible to add the xiaomi mi virtual device into my genymotion?

Comment: Check this link https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#maximum-amount-devices-physical-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible:

> **Why can't I deploy some third-party devices (Amazon, Nokia, etc.)?**
>
> The Genymotion ROM is built from official Android sources, AOSP.
>
> Amazon, Nokia and other brands do not provide the whole source codes
>   of their products. Therefore we cannot port their ROM into Genymotion.

Comment: I have to check one issue which is only occur in MI device... what is other way to do that.